# With SQL Server format date as '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%P' / '2012-04-05 11:56am'

Tags: sql, sql-server, formatting

I've always found SQL Server date formatting to be counter intuitive. I am pretty sure I already know the only answer is to use a slew of convert and string functions but thought I would ask just in case.

How do you get SQL Server to format a `datetime` to look like:

```
%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%P or '2012-04-05 11:56am'
```

My current approach involves pulling back data with `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120)` and then looping server/client side in code. This I find inefficient in some scenarios when exporting data say to CSV.

Comment: Instead of returning a `Varchar(19)` why not return a `date` and let the client code format it

Comment: I could easily return a UNIX timestamp and do my formatting in code.  My question is specifically about how can I leverage the database to do the formatting.  This is preferred in some scenarios like doing a large CSV dump or interfacing with other applications where my sole control over the format is the SQL used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the real answer is "You don't", unless you upgrade your SQL Server instances to SQL Server 2012.

[FORMAT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
    cast(datepart(YYYY, GETDATE()) as varchar) + '-' +
    right('0' + cast(datepart(MM, GETDATE()) as varchar), 2) + '-' +
    right('0' + cast(datepart(DD, GETDATE()) as varchar), 2) + ' ' +
    LTRIM(RIGHT(cast(GETDATE() AS varchar), 8))
```

Comment: Ahh, now I feel bad and don't know who to give the points to.  I should not use SO to rant against MSSQL...

Comment: I don't care who gets the points, just upvote the ones that were helpful to you.

Comment: @ficuscr: Yeah, I thought this was one of the approaches you meant by "a slew of convert and string functions". If this or another answer is the better answer, definitely accept that one (instead of mine!).

Comment: @Peter: Exactly what I meant by slew :)  Well we have two good examples of how to do this should one be forced to.  Gives the thread merit at least.  I personally just can't bring myself to use something like this.  Think the answer is "you don't" - upgrade instead to 2012,

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @d AS datetime;
SET @d = '2012-04-04 16:43:00'
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @d, 120), 11) 
       +  RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @d, 131), 12, 5)), 5) 
       + LOWER(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @d, 131), 2))
--2012-04-04 04:43pm
```